# Change upload_tmp_dir without access to php.ini

Tags: php

so i'm currently working on a website hosted at one, their policy also sais that customers are not allowed to ask for modification of this file (because as users, we don't have access to that file).

They have not set the `upload_tmp_dir` so it defaults out to their root, and not my ftp's. Hence - why i can't upload files to my server because `move_uploaded_files();` is targeting that very directory.

I'm now wondering if there is any way to bypass this? Setting the temporary location without having access to php.ini?

Any file-script that uploads to a set directory would really save my day.
Thanks!

Comment: Simple: don’t upload files. Using JS send binary blobs to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

use `ini_set('upload_tmp_dir','your_directory_path')` function

Comment: hmm. `ini_set('upload_tmp_dir','./uploads/')` doesn't seem to work. still getting `Unable to move '/run/tmp/php1pcjy9'` unfortunately.

Comment: put your whole path in that like /home/public_html bla bla

Comment: this does not work, because you have to set the temp dir before the request gets handed off the php. by the time execution passes to php, the uploaded files have already been stored in the temp dir. I might be wrong tho.

Answer (score -1):

You can set it in either the php.ini or the httpd.conf as it is under MODE `PHP_INI_SYSTEM`

see https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php

Comment: As stated in the question and the title, I do not have access to `php.ini`.